# Cucumber/Capybara: check that a page does NOT have content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

Using Cucumber and Capybara, is there a way to verify that a string is NOT present on a page?

For example, how would I write the opposite of this step:

```
Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  page.should have_content(arg1)
end
```

This passes if `arg1` is present.

How would I write a step that *fails* if `arg1` is found?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_no_text%3F-instance_method

There is a `has_no_content` matcher in Capybara. So you can write

```
  Then /^I should not see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
    page.should have_no_content(arg1)
  end
```

Comment: I'm amazed how much faster this is than `assert !page.has_content?(arg)`

Comment: @MichaelDiscenza, you are right, see more information - https://github.com/ngauthier/capybara-slow_finder_errors

Answer (score 16):

In Rspec 3.4 currently (2016) this is the recommended way to test for not having content:

```
expect(page).not_to have_content(arg1)
```

Comment: Where do you see that this is recommended over `expect(page).to have_no_content(arg1)`? It seems like there's no way for not_to to know not to wait for the content to be on the page, which is what `have_content` would do, I would think.

Comment: Deprecation Warnings are shown when using ´expect(page).to have_no_content(arg1)´

Comment: @RobHughes, the depreciation warnings you speak of must have been removed in rspec 3.5.4/capybara 2.6.2. Per the docs: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends - `Capybara's RSpec matchers, however, are smart enough to handle either form. The two following statements are functionally equivalent: expect(page).not_to have_xpath('a'), expect(page).to have_no_xpath('a')`

Comment: With Hotwire ( rails7 ) I cant get any of these to work.
`expect(page).not_to have_content('Company Mismatch', wait: 10)`
Also doesnt work.
I needed to put a `sleep 1` before the expect. this must be because of Hotwires DOM swapping shenanigans.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use **should_not** if you want it read a little better:

```
Then /^I should not see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  page.should_not have_content(arg1)
end
```

Some more info: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs

Comment: Note that this will only work properly for javascript tests if you have Capybara::RSpecMatchers included for your spec. I just ran into that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15253235/125377

Comment: Use `has_no_content?` instead. That will trigger capybara's internal wait. Otherwise, it will prematurely fail if you're waiting for the content to disappear from the page.

Answer (score 4):

currently, you can use:

```
Then /^I not see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  expect(page).to have_no_content(arg1)
end
```

And if the content is found in the page, your test is red

Comment: This is the correct syntax. If you're using expect(), I would reword your spec removing "should" from the description. More assertive! :)

Comment: Thank you @Rimian. I fixed that!

Answer (score -4):

Oh, wait, I figured it out.  This works:

```
Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  page.has_content?(arg1) == false
end
```

Comment: Your code does not assert the content. I guess that if you change false for true, your test will still pass.

Comment: This had tripped me up several times. Either you use `assert page.has_content...` or `page.should have_content...` Can't mix the two styles together. Good call, @PhilippeRathé.